# How do you reset a “$timeout”, and disable a “$watch()” angularJS?

Tags: angularjs

How do you reset a `$timeout`, and disable a `$watch()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key to both is assigning the result of the function to a variable.

To cleanup the timeout, just “.cancel()” it:

```
var customTimeout = $timeout(function () {
// arbitrary code 
}, 55);
$timeout.cancel(customTimeout);
```

The same applies to “$interval()”.

To disable a watch, just call it.

```
var deregisterWatchFn = $rootScope.$watch(‘someGloballyAvailableProperty’, function (newVal) {
if (newVal) {
// we invoke that deregistration function, to disable the watch
deregisterWatchFn();
...
}
});
```

Comment: source of answer may be- https://www.codementor.io/angularjs/tutorial/angularjs-interview-questions-sample-answers

Answer (score 1):

You already got most of the answer, but one other point that might be useful is that you should always clean up a watch when the relevant scope is destroyed, so the following pattern is quite useful:

```
$scope.$on('$destroy', $scope.$watch(function() { /* ... */ });
```

This will ensure the `$watch` is always cancelled automatically on destruction of the scope.

Of course if you want to destroy the watch manually you would have to also save the result so you could call it, but this pattern lets you avoid that most of the time.

Answer (score 0):

You can clear a `$timeout` by using `$timeout.cancel` like so:

```
var myTimer = $timeout(function() { /* ... */ }, 5000);
$timeout.cancel(yourTimer);
```

You can clear a `$watch()` by the deregister function it returns:

```
var dereg = $scope.$watch(function() { /* ... */ });
dereg(); // watcher is now gone
```